# So with no more .NET Standard support from .NET Core 3 onwards how do you share code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So with .NET Core 3 [no longer supporting](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324) .NET Standard (and .NET 5 beyond that being in the same boat.) Lets say today I have the following applications:

- WebForms .NET 4.61
- .NET MVC 5
- .NET Core 2.x

with "common" code, enums etc. as .NET Standard  2.0. And now I want to build a .NET Core 3.x application.

So for simple POCO's, enums, types etc. this is no issue. However for anything supporting anything more complex (and currently .NET Standard 2.0 compliant) what is the solution?

It seems to me I can no longer share code between WebForms, .NET Core 2.x, .NET Core 3.x, .NET 5. So assuming I have to support those legacy platforms (Webforms, .Net Core 2) what options am I left with here?

Comment: The link you provided says nothing about .NET Core 3 no longer supporting .NET Standard. It talks about ASP.NET Core 3.0 only being supported by .NET Core 3.0 and not the .NET Framework. Have you added the wrong link or misread the post?

Comment: @SimplyGed I am hoping I have misread the post..... Why does the post talk about Microsoft.Extensions still remaining as .NET Standard then? So is the inference that .NET Core 3, .NET will still support .NET Standard 2.0 moving forward? I cannot see any statement directly in this regard.

Comment: [This Blog Post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) announcing dotnet 5 says they’re still considering if net standard will be needed in the future when all the dotnets come together, I heard the same on a podcast recently. Don’t think it’s decided yet but presumably if they’re still considering if it’s needed for dotnet 5 then it’s still around in core 3.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/: "Given many of the API additions in .NET Standard 2.1 require runtime changes in order to be meaningful, .NET Framework 4.8 will remain on .NET Standard 2.0 rather than implement .NET Standard 2.1. .NET Core 3.0 as well as upcoming versions of Xamarin, Mono, and Unity will be updated to implement .NET Standard 2.1."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core) and [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) are different things. .NET Core is the runtime and API like .NET Framework, and ASP.NET Core is a web framework like ASP.NET. ASP.NET Core indirectly targets (1.x and 2.x via .NET Standard) or is built-in as framework dependency within (3.0 and later on) .NET Core but they are different things.

**.NET Core 3.0** supports .NET Standard 2.1 that is downward compatible to .NET Standard 2.0, therefore it supports .NET Standard 2.0 (and even to .NET Standard 1.0)

**.NET Standard 2.1** is the new .NET Standard that is only supported by .NET Core 3.0 currently and will never be supported by .NET Framework, so itself is meaningless unless a new mono release supports it.

**ASP.NET Core 2.2** targets .NET Standard 2.0 therefore it is supported by .NET Core 2.2 and .NET Framework 4.7.2+ (also 4.6.1+ but with problems)

**ASP.NET Core 3.0** is a framework dependency within .NET Core 3.0. ASP.NET Core 3.0 itself no longer works on all .NET Standard 2.0 implementations but only .NET Core 3.0, which supports libraries that target .NET Standard 2.0. The only limit is that it will no longer work on .NET Framework.

**.NET 5** is a later version of .NET Core, therefore it will continue supporting .NET Standard 2.1, .NET Standard 2.0 and downwards.

Conclusion and Suggestion:

- Libraries that targets .NET Standard 2.0 could work on both .NET Core (from 2.0 to .NET 5 and later on) and .NET Framework, therefore it could be used for sharing code between all of your applications.
- .NET Framework is will be dead, ASP.NET as well. There is no information about whether there will be an easy way to migrate an existing ASP.NET project to .NET 5, but I guess not. So a complete refactoring from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core is needed if you want to targets any futural .NET.
- .NET Core 3.0 supports Windows Forms and WPF, not something like "Windows Forms Core" or "WPF Core", so the API is mostly unchanged on migration from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.0. So it could be easy to migrate a Windows Forms or WPF application to .NET Core if it is purely a UI project without other framework dependencies on .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The announcement of Net Core 5 was for MS to draw a line in the sand and merge all of the 3 different platforms together. The jump from Net Framework to Net Core 5 will probably be significant - but the point is, there "shouldnt" be a need for Net Standard any more (since that was only ever intended as a bridge between Framework and Core anyway.. It was fairly obvious from the start of Core that this day was coming. Finally with the announcement of Net Core 5, we know that day. The intention (I believe) is that Net Core 5 will remove the need for Standard, and make Framework enter retirement phase for new development.